# Import error on installed package using setup.py

Tags: python, import, python-2.7, setuptools

I have a problem with using `setup.py` to setup a python package. First, I have the following directory setup:

```
maindir
   |- setup.py
   |-mymodule
         |- __init__.py
         |- mainmodule.py
         |-subdir
             |- __init__.py
             |- submodule.py
```

i.e. the project directory contains the `setup.py` and a directory `mymodule`, which in itself contains two python modules in two directories. 
The file `submodule.py` contains just

```
teststring = "hello world"
```

`mainmodule.py` contains:

```
from .subdir import submodule
mainstring = "42"
```

and `setup.py` contains:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name = "mytestmodule",
    version = "0.0.1",
    description = ("A simple module."),
    packages=['mymodule'],
)
```

When I do `from mymodule import mainmodule` with `ipython` from within `sourceTest` the behaviour works as expected and I can reference e.g. `mainmodule.submodule.teststring` which gives me the string `hello world`.

On the other side, when I install this 'package' using `python setup.py install` and try to do the same (from within some other directory), I get an import error:

```
In [1]: from mymodule import mainmodule
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/alexander/<ipython-input-1-cf4c9bafa487> in <module>()
----> 1 from mymodule import mainmodule

/home/alexander/build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/mymodule/mainmodule.py in <module>()

ImportError: No module named subdir
```

I do not see what I have done wrong, as I followed a [Getting started tutorial](http://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html) and [rules for importing intra-packages](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages-in-multiple-directories). I suppose my mistake is a really tiny one, but I cannot spot it and help is appreciated.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You have to list all packages in `setup`, including subpackages:

```
setup(
    name = "mytestmodule",
    version = "0.0.1",
    description = ("A simple module."),
    packages=['mymodule', 'mymodule.subdir'],
)
```

Or you can use `setuptools`'s magic function `find_packages`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name = "mytestmodule",
    version = "0.0.1",
    description = ("A simple module."),
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

This is mentioned [here](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/examples.html#pure-python-distribution-by-package):

> If you have sub-packages, they must be explicitly listed in packages,
>   but any entries in package_dir automatically extend to sub-packages.
>   (In other words, *the Distutils does not scan your source tree, trying
>   to figure out which directories correspond to Python packages* by
>   looking for `__init__.py` files.)

Comment: Is this described somewhere? Is there some documentation on the content of `setup` on `distutils`? It does not seem easy to find representative documentation.

Comment: For further reference that elaborates on how `package_dir` is used recursively to find sub-packages, provided that those sub-packages are listed in `packages`, read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages).

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify your each modules explicitly. Instead of maintaining the complexity of adding module to setup.py everytime, you may use the `find_packages` method from `setuptools`.

`find_packages` takes two optional arguments:

1. `where` which is default to `'.'` i.e your curdir.
2. `exclude` list of stuff to exclude

I usually have tests in my repo, so I use:

```
from setuptools import find_packages

packages=find_packages(exclude=["*.tests", "*.tests.*", "tests.*", "tests"]),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had `scriptname.py:main` in my setup.py console_scripts, the `.py` is redundant.