# ImportError while doing python setup.py test

Tags: python, bash, unit-testing, import

I'm making a simple python app. I don't know if I am doing it correctly or not so please correct me in the comments or if you have an answer for this

Error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'taskhandler'
```

and:

```
ImportError: No module named 'styles' while doing `python3 setup.py test
```

File Structure:

```
.
├── MANIFEST.in
├── pydotask.egg-info
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── not-zip-safe
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── README.md
├── setup.py
├── task_mod
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── pydo.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── taskhandler.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── pydo.py
│   ├── styles
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── termcolor.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   └── text_style.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── termcolor.py
│   │   └── text_style.py
│   ├── taskhandler.py
│   └── tasks.csv
└── update.txt

5 directories, 22 files
```

'task_mod/pydo.py':

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

''' To Do App in Python '''

import sys, os
import taskhandler as task
from styles import text_style as text
from styles import termcolor
```

`task_mod/taskhandler.py`:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys, os
import csv
from styles import termcolor
from styles import text_style as text
```

`setup.py`

```python
from setuptools import setup

def readme():
    with open('README.md') as readme:
        return readme.read()

setup(
        name = 'pydotask',
        version = '0.2',
        description = 'PyDo is a CLI Application to keep you on track with your tasks and projects',
        long_description = readme(),
        classifiers = [
            'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
            'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
            'Topic :: Office/Business :: Scheduling'
            ],
        keywords = 'utilities office schedule task reminder',
        url = '',
        author = 'Abhishta Gatya',
        author_email = 'abhishtagatya@yahoo.com',
        packages = ['task_mod'],
        scripts = ['task_mod/pydo'],
        python_requires = '>=3',
        include_package_data = True,
        zip_safe = False
        )
```

How do I get around this problem?

Note: If I run `python3 task_mod/pydo.py` it works fine! But when I try testing it it, it gives 2 ImportErrors.

Comment: Is this not because of the line `#!/usr/bin/env python3` you have in the beginning of `pydo.py` and `taskhandler.py`?

Comment: @Iva that’s just the interpreter path

Comment: is that what has been causing it? hang on

Comment: @AbhishtaGatya show your setup.py

Comment: same results @Iva

Comment: @Steampunkery Done its there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that you provide a package named `task_mod` in `setup.py`. It means, you should only `import task_mod` or `import task_mod.blah`, never `import blah`. Because you do not provide `blah` in your library. Trying changing the imports to the absolute ones.

Second, if you still want a relative import (this is a common practice to do withing a single library — it is easier to maintain the code then), you should import relatively: `from .styles import termcolor` (note the dot).

Third, the relative imports only affect the modules & packages, not the scripts that you execute direcly (because `pydo.py` is the package `__main__`, not `task_mod.pydo`, and it changes everything). For the scripts, you have two choices to do it properly:

Choice A (so-so): Always import absolute package/module name (`import task_mod.taskhandler as tashhandler` in your pydo.py; also `from task_mod.styles import termcolor`, etc).

Choice B (best practice): Never export any scripts as part of the library (only for building/testing/CI/CD purposes). Instead, export the entry points for the console scripts (google: setuptools entry points).

`setup(
    ....
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'pydo = task_mod.pydo:main',
        ],
    },
)`

And, of course, define the `main()` function in that module.

The shebangs (`#!...python3`) are completely irrelevant here.

---

**UPD:**

If you have problems with importing, please keep this in mind:

You should make your package to be on the PYTHONPATH env var (or `sys.path` internal variable), one way or another. This is exactly where Python looks for things when you do `import things`.

You can `print(sys.path)` before any imports to see why it happens this way — the first element will be your script's dir, and it will be varying between `task_mod/pydo.py` & `setup.py` calls.

When you run a script in the main project dir (`python3 setup.py`), `sys.path` starts with the project's dir. `task_mod` is there, you can import it. Also, when you do something like `pip install -e .`, the packages will also be "installed" into the Python/virtualenv list of libraries, but in a different way.

However, when you run `python3 task_mod/pydo.py`, you current dir is `.../task_mod/`. There, you cannot find `task_mod` package (because it is one level upper).

On the opposite side, when your run `python3 setup.py`, your current dir is the project's dir, and you cannot import `styles` & `taskhandler` directly as you did innitially (without prefixing them by `task_mod.`).

This is exactly the reason why you should never rely on the `sys.path`, and never use the scripts directly, and assume its location. Because it varies.

You can try running `PYTHONPATH=. python3 task_mod/pydo.py` to make it work the same as for `setup.py` (or `PYTHONPATH=./task_mod/ python3 setup.py` to make it the same as for `task_mod/pydo.py`). But this is a dirty hack to make it work. Instead, you should layout your library properly, according to Python's conventions.

Comment: Dashbang? Do you mean shebang?

Comment: Oops. Yes, the shebangs. Sorry :-) Fixed.

Comment: now when I try to run pydo.py, I get an ImportError saying no module named 'task_mod'

Comment: never mind it works when I run setup.py but not when I run pydo, can you please tell me whats going on? :) but thanks for helping me

Comment: @AbhishtaGatya I've added an update for you, explaining the `sys.path`/`PYTHONPATH`, which is used for imports.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify all modules used in setup.py, not just the top-level folder. So in your setup.py file, replace the line `packages = ['task_mod'],` with `packages = ['task_mod', 'task_mod.styles', 'task_mod.taskhandler'],`.

Alternatively, without changing your `setup.py`, you can import with `import task_mod.styles` or with `from task_mod import styles`. Then you can use files in styles like `styles.termcolor`.

Or, you can use setuptool's black magic function `find_packages` like so: `packages = find_packages(),`

[Related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368054/import-error-on-installed-package-using-setup-py)