# pip does not install subdirectories

Tags: python, pip

I wrote a [package](https://pypi.org/project/getchlib/). It has subdirectory called `keynames` containing key names assigned to values they are represented in stdin. When I ran `python setup.py sdist`, `keynames` was added to source distribution:

```
running sdist
running egg_info
writing getchlib.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to getchlib.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to getchlib.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'getchlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
adding license file 'LICENSE'
writing manifest file 'getchlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running check
creating getchlib-1.0.7
creating getchlib-1.0.7/getchlib
creating getchlib-1.0.7/getchlib.egg-info
creating getchlib-1.0.7/getchlib/keynames
copying files to getchlib-1.0.7...
copying LICENSE -> getchlib-1.0.7
copying README.md -> getchlib-1.0.7
copying setup.py -> getchlib-1.0.7
copying getchlib/__init__.py -> getchlib-1.0.7/getchlib
copying getchlib/ctrl.py -> getchlib-1.0.7/getchlib
copying getchlib/decorators.py -> getchlib-1.0.7/getchlib
copying getchlib/getkey.py -> getchlib-1.0.7/getchlib
copying getchlib/hotkey.py -> getchlib-1.0.7/getchlib
copying getchlib/pressed.py -> getchlib-1.0.7/getchlib
copying getchlib/printer.py -> getchlib-1.0.7/getchlib
copying getchlib/term.py -> getchlib-1.0.7/getchlib
copying getchlib/unix.py -> getchlib-1.0.7/getchlib
copying getchlib/windows.py -> getchlib-1.0.7/getchlib
copying getchlib.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> getchlib-1.0.7/getchlib.egg-info
copying getchlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> getchlib-1.0.7/getchlib.egg-info
copying getchlib.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> getchlib-1.0.7/getchlib.egg-info
copying getchlib.egg-info/top_level.txt -> getchlib-1.0.7/getchlib.egg-info
copying getchlib/keynames/__init__.py -> getchlib-1.0.7/getchlib/keynames
copying getchlib/keynames/raw.py -> getchlib-1.0.7/getchlib/keynames
Writing getchlib-1.0.7/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'getchlib-1.0.7' (and everything under it)
```

In `getchlib-1.0.7.tar.gz` is that directory.
It's also in [source distribution at PyPI](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/af/ec/5860417655dae02de063ee606d015b9bc5b4fc612d5d251d8192d4365780/getchlib-1.0.7.tar.gz).
But when I called `pip install getchlib`,  `~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/getchlib` did not contain `keynames` subdirectory:

```
[adam@gastan site-packages]$ ls ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/getchlib -l
total 44
-rw-r--r-- 1 adam adam 1137 Dec  9 21:07 ctrl.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 adam adam  205 Dec  9 21:07 decorators.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 adam adam  294 Dec  9 21:07 getkey.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 adam adam 1976 Dec  9 21:07 hotkey.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 adam adam   68 Dec  9 21:07 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 adam adam  231 Dec  9 21:07 pressed.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 adam adam  112 Dec  9 21:07 printer.py
drwxr-xr-x 2 adam adam 4096 Dec  9 21:07 __pycache__
-rw-r--r-- 1 adam adam  449 Dec  9 21:07 term.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 adam adam 2350 Dec  9 21:07 unix.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 adam adam  429 Dec  9 21:07 windows.py
```

And therefore, `import getchlib` failed with ImportError:

```py
[GCC 11.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import getchlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/adam/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/getchlib/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import keynames
ImportError: cannot import name 'keynames' from partially initialized module 'getchlib' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/adam/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/getchlib/__init__.py)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15368107/7976758

Comment: Pretty non-intuittive behavior.... I added the file in MANIFEST and also in egg-info/SOURCES.txt and I have to add it also to setup.py . Could be puzzling for beginner to packaging(as me).